# Why do I keep getting errors when installing devtools in R Studio?

Tags: r, devtools

After running many commands in the terminal from ubuntu 22 and R Studio I managed to install the devtools package. The problem is that after running the command dev_mode(on=T), I receive the following error: Error: [ENOENT] Failed to realize '/home/user/R-dev': no such file or directory. I can't find any solution for this problem. I have updated R Studio to the latest version...Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you!

I ran several commands and in vain.

Edit: Thanks for the reply. So, I need to follow the following steps to install the AnnotationBustR package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AnnotationBustR/vignettes/AnnotationBustR-vignette.html): the error with devtools is older not from now but now I really need to install the AnnotationBustR package, so I have to solve it. I get the error when running: dev_mode(on=T).

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ro_RO.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=ro_RO.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=ro_RO.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ro_RO.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.5 usethis_2.1.6 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10       rstudioapi_0.14   magrittr_2.0.3    pkgload_1.3.2     xtable_1.8-4     
 [6] R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.1.0       fastmap_1.1.1     urlchecker_1.0.1  stringr_1.5.0    
[11] tools_4.2.3       pkgbuild_1.4.0    sessioninfo_1.2.2 miniUI_0.1.1.1    cli_3.6.1        
[16] remotes_2.4.2     htmltools_0.5.5   ellipsis_0.3.2    digest_0.6.31     lifecycle_1.0.3  
[21] crayon_1.5.2      processx_3.8.0    shiny_1.7.4       purrr_1.0.1       callr_3.7.3      
[26] later_1.3.0       htmlwidgets_1.6.2 profvis_0.3.7     vctrs_0.6.1       fs_1.6.1         
[31] promises_1.2.0.1  ps_1.7.4          memoise_2.0.1     glue_1.6.2        cachem_1.0.7     
[36] mime_0.12         stringi_1.7.12    compiler_4.2.3    prettyunits_1.1.1 httpuv_1.6.9
```

Comment: RStudio may have little to do with it. What version of R and devtools have you tried? Did you just call `dev_mode()` or do you have any arguments to it? Are both `/home/user` and `/home/user/R-dev` directories (not files) and writable by your user? Please [edit] your question and paste the output from `sessionInfo()` into a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: hei, i edited the text abeove, thanks

Comment: Do you know that you need the dev version to do what you do? That part of the vignette is if you suspect the CRAN version has problems/issues that only the github version will resolve. It might be that you don't _need_ to go the `dev_mode` route.